# Can Google classify document types such as W-2 forms and W-9 forms?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I need to determine the document type first, as we have a bunch of documents. Only after that can I use a specialized processor.

I've tried the Custom Document Classifier in Workbench and trained the model for W-2 and W-9 forms. However, I'm not getting the expected labels when evaluating either W-2 or W-9. Additionally, for your reference, I also have a 'none' label.

Comment: Can you provide more information:

Did you follow the guide listed here? https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-classification-processor

How did you label the documents? 

And how are you trying to test the processor output?

Comment: Yes, I've followed the documentation. I created three buckets for W-2, W-9, and 'none.' Each bucket contains the respective forms, with the 'none' bucket being distinct from W-2 and W-9 forms. I created labels for W-2, W-9, and 'none,' and imported the appropriate documents using Auto Splitting.

However, when I evaluate the 1099-R form, it shows a high W-2 precision.

Comment: How much training data did you provide? In general, performance and accuracy will improve with more training data that is similar to the types of input you expect to receive.

Comment: I've added 12 documents in each label.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Followup from comments

Ok, I'd recommend adding more training data than 12 of each. (You'll have to experiment to see how much it takes to get the accuracy you need) Depending on the variety of "other" documents you want to identify, you could need significantly more of those to avoid model bias.

You can also apply for allowlisting to the Lending Splitter/Classifier processor here and you wouldn't need to train your own model.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc_6s8jsHLZWWE0aSX0bdmk24XDoPiE_oq5enDApLcp1VKJ-Q/viewform?gxids=7826